# What have I do to create a "folder" into an SVN branch using Eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, svn, version-control, eclipse-plugin, subversive

I am not so into **SVN** and I have the following doubt.

In my repository I have the following strucutre:

[image]

As you can see I have 2 branches: **features** and **rleases**.

Into the **releases** branch there are 2 "folder" (or maybe are branches in turn).

I need to create a new "folder" into the **releases** branch named **4.0.0-beta-fix**.

So I select the **releases** branch, right click with the mouse an select the **New** voice.

But now the SVN Eclipse plugin give me 2 different possible options:

- **Folder**
- **Branch**

These:

[image]

So what have I to chose to replicate the **releases** inner structure and create a new container that have to contains a new version of my sofware?

What is the difference between create a branch and a folder in this specific case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Branch creates a copy of some other folder. This is what you want to do when creating a new release: you create a copy of a folder in a specific revision.

Creating a folder would just create a new empty folder in the repository.

Comment: I explain better my situation: I have a different version of the project on my PC. I have not to create a copy of an existing SVN folder. I have to create a container where upload the project from my PC. So have I to create a foler instead a branch?

Comment: So your local code is not under version control so far? If this is true then yes: you can create a new folder in the repository, then check that empty folder out, copy your project files into it, and finally commit. Another (maybe easier) way would be to use "Import...". This allows you to add local files to a repository folder. I think the import wizard will allow you to directly create a new folder into which your files will be imported.